# Pass arguments to script

Tags: bash, shell-script, arguments

I have shell script that pass arguments to script, like this:

```
script.sh argA argB arg1 arg2 arg3 argN
```

ArgA and ArgB consider for name and family.

Arg1 ... argN are phone numbers. (Maybe 1 to N depend to user input)

Here is my script:

```
for var in "$@"
do
    echo "$var"
done
```

`"$@"` pass all arguments, but I need do this from third argument and use ArgA, ArgB somewhere else in my script.

Any recommendation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `shift` to move down the line of parameters.

```
name=$1
family=$2
shift 2

for var in "$@"
do
  something_with "$var"
done
```

`shift 2` will essentially remove parameters 1 and 2 and restart at 3 (`arg1`).